# using Heroku's guide to uploading to AWS S3 with Python, getting 403 back

Tags: python, heroku, amazon-s3

I am going through Heroku's tutorial on uploading images to Amazon using Javascript https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python .

It seems I've done everything according to the tutorial, but I'm still getting the 403 Access Denied error.

My bucket is called media.better.herokuapp.com, which corresponds to the `S3_BUCKET` environment variable. `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` variables are carefully copied from the Amazon web interface. And these are not user credentials, but account credentials, that

> "provide unlimited access to your AWS resources."

The code that generates request urls:

```
@login_required
def sign_s3(request):

    AWS_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_KEY')
    S3_BUCKET = os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET')

    object_name = request.GET.get('s3_object_name')
    mime_type = request.GET.get('s3_object_type')

    expires = long(time.time()+10)
    amz_headers = "x-amz-acl:public-read"

    put_request = "PUT\n\n%s\n%d\n%s\n/%s/%s" % (mime_type, expires, amz_headers, S3_BUCKET, object_name)

    signature = base64.encodestring(hmac.new(AWS_SECRET_KEY, put_request, sha1).digest())
    signature = urllib.quote(urllib.quote_plus(signature.strip()))

    url = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s' % (S3_BUCKET, object_name)

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({
        'signed_request': '%s?AWSAccessKeyId=%s&Expires=%d&Signature=%s' % (url, AWS_ACCESS_KEY, expires, signature),
         'url': url
      })
    )
```

the code that actually sends the requests, which is based on [s3upload.js library](https://github.com/flyingsparx/s3upload-coffee-javascript), again all according to the Heroku tutorial:

```
<script>

  function s3_upload(){
    var status_elem = document.getElementById("status");
    var url_elem = document.getElementById("avatar_url");
    var preview_elem = document.getElementById("preview");
    var s3upload = new S3Upload({
        file_dom_selector: 'file',
        s3_sign_put_url: '/sign_s3/',

        onProgress: function(percent, message) {
            status_elem.innerHTML = 'Upload progress: ' + percent + '% ' + message;
        },
        onFinishS3Put: function(url) {
            status_elem.innerHTML = 'Upload completed. Uploaded to: '+ url;
            url_elem.value = url;
            preview_elem.innerHTML = '<img src="'+url+'" style="width:300px;" />';
        },
        onError: function(status) {
            console.log(status);
            status_elem.innerHTML = 'Upload error: ' + status;
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

the CORS config for my bucket is supposed to allow connections from all origins:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And the log for my bucket says there were two requests, one `OPTIONS` and one `PUT`. The first one passed (judging by the code 200), and the second one didn't.

```
149cbdd537e09d49c6f979053efd3c99ab2a75b0d80bb72dabe40782d9f6e68e media.better.herokuapp.com [25/Feb/2015:03:58:32 +0000] 103.247.121.189 - 5AFE4968D1986AFD REST.OPTIONS.PREFLIGHT default_name "OPTIONS /default_name?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJTAAJTDNVNPEVKJA&Expires=1424836708&Signature=9G6eOA1%252BUDhpGcem4JOODG2up1c%253D HTTP/1.1" 200 - - - 12 - "http://localhost:8000/game/c54b02c3/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36" -
149cbdd537e09d49c6f979053efd3c99ab2a75b0d80bb72dabe40782d9f6e68e media.better.herokuapp.com [25/Feb/2015:03:58:33 +0000] 103.247.121.189 - 73F995CAE6564A1A REST.PUT.OBJECT default_name "PUT /default_name?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJTAAJTDNVNPEVKJA&Expires=1424836708&Signature=9G6eOA1%252BUDhpGcem4JOODG2up1c%253D HTTP/1.1" 403 AccessDenied 321 - 5 - "http://localhost:8000/game/c54b02c3/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36" -
```

So what else is missing?

The options I'm looking at are:

- there's something wrong with the uploaded file naming - if you look
  at the request.GET dict, the JS library names all the input files
  `default_name`
- the account credentials for AWS somehow enable    `OPTIONS` requests
  but disable `PUT` requests, and these have to be    addressed
  specifically, although AWS manual says they are    system-wide
- the `localhost` origin has to be added to the CORS config separately somehow

Or there is something else?

Comment: The 403 is coming from your heroku app, not S3. Are you signed in?

Comment: @Enrico I am not even using Heroku yet, just developing locally

Comment: Sorry, I got confused by `media.better.herokuapp.com`, but my point still stands... `http://localhost:8000/game/c54b02c3/` is returning 403, not S3. Your function is decorated with `@login_required`, so are you logged into your web app on localhost?

Comment: @Enrico yes, I am logged in, and the function works and outputs Json data. Otherwise it wouldn't have returned the request URL to the JS function on the client side, and the request to Amazon wouldn't have happened at all; but it did, and this generated AWS logs. But what makes you think it's my function that returns 403? According to the AWS log format http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html , `http://localhost:8000/game/c54b02c3/` is just HTTP Referrer header.